# Computing the area of a region from two overlapping circles

Tags: integration, area

Here's my given problem:

```
Compute the area of the region of the graph of r=4sinθ and the graph of r=4cosθ.
```

I know from

```
 r=2acosθ and r=2asinθ
```

that the centers are (2,0) and (0,2). I also know graphically that these two equations are overlapping circles. I set the equations equal to one another to get the points of intersection, which are 0 or 2π and 3π/2 for 4sinθ and π/2 and π for 4cosθ (frankly I am still not entirely sure how to choose which function's angles for integration bounds).

Just broadly/conceptually, what should I try to look for or integrate to find this overlapping area? I'm having trouble figuring out how to get those properties of that shape. Several of the integrations I tried just equaled zero, and common sense tells me there's more to it than getting the area of a sector of one of the circles because the zone of interest doesn't go all the way to the centers of either of the circles.

Comment: Note: I tried following the example in my book, but it has r equations that don't integrate as 0 when I apply the formula and subtract one area from the other.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the area of the gray part in the following figure :

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Since $A,B$ is a point for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}$ in $r=4\cos\theta$ respectively, and $A,B$ is a point for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4},0$ in $r=4\sin\theta$ respectively, the area is
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac 12(4\cos\theta)^2d\theta+\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac 12(4\sin\theta)^2d\theta=\color{red}{2\pi -4}.$$